# Code to assign persons by age to different households

Tags: python, numpy

I am generating a synthetic population for which number of households of each size and age composition of each household are known. I am trying to assign persons by age to each of these households.

The total number of persons in each age group (column sum) should sum to

```
Children   45196
Adult     148949
Senior     12195
```

while the total number of persons in households of each size (1-20) should sum to

```
1    2276
2    9366
3   23739
4   47636
5   42475
6   28338
7    3675
8    3728
9    3672
10   3830
11   3894
12   3792
13   3770
14   3710
15   3795
16   3648
17   3672
18   3744
19   3800
20   3780
```

I tried to code this in python as a set of linear equations. However, the presence of negative solutions does not help. The code is as below, how can it be modified to generate the total number of persons of each of the age groups in different households.

```
# Total Population
Population = 206340

# Number of Children, Adults and Seniors
Demography = np.array([ 45196, 148949,  12195])

# Number of households by size
Household_size_distribution = np.array([2276, 4683, 7913,11909,8495,4723,525,466,408,383,354,316,290,265,253,228,216,208,200,189])

# Probability that a person of a certain age group belongs to a household of a certain size
Age_Composition = np.array([[7.000e-04, 7.702e-01, 2.291e-01],
       [1.890e-02, 8.066e-01, 1.745e-01],
       [1.486e-01, 8.027e-01, 4.870e-02],
       [2.519e-01, 7.180e-01, 3.010e-02],
       [2.732e-01, 6.719e-01, 5.490e-02],
       [3.046e-01, 6.337e-01, 6.170e-02]])

# Store Age compositions
x = np.zeros((20,3),dtype=np.float)
x[:5,:] = Age_Composition[:5,:]
# Age composition same for households with more than 6 persons
x[5:20,:] = np.repeat(Age_Composition[5][np.newaxis,:], 15,0)

# Normalize the age compositions column-wise: Children, Adults and Seniors
y = np.zeros((20,3),dtype=np.float)
y[:,0] = x[:20,0]/np.sum(x[:20,0])
y[:,1] = x[:20,1]/np.sum(x[:20,1])
y[:,2] = x[:20,2]/np.sum(x[:20,2])

# Store Coefficients of 60 variables
w = np.zeros((23,60),dtype=np.float)
w[:20,:3] = x

z = np.zeros((20,3),dtype=np.float)
z[:,0] = y[:,0] 
w[20] = np.reshape(z,(60))

z = np.zeros((20,3),dtype=np.float)
z[:,1] = y[:,1] 
w[21] = np.reshape(z,(60))

z = np.zeros((20,3),dtype=np.float)
z[:,2] = y[:,2] 
w[22] = np.reshape(z,(60))

rollnumber = np.arange(0,60,step=3)
for i in range(20):
  w[i]=np.roll(w[i],rollnumber[i]) 

# Ax=B  
A = w
B = np.zeros((23,1),dtype=np.int)
B[:20,:] = new_Household_size_distribution[:,None]*np.arange(1,21)[:,None]
B[20:,:] = Demography[:,None]

# Solution to the set of linear equations
f=np.matmul(np.linalg.pinv(A),B)
f=np.reshape(f,60)
```

Comment: You could add `numpy` as another tag to get more attention.

Comment: I am really sorry, but this isn't a programming problem, it is a mathematical problem and what you are trying to do is mathematically wrong, which is why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to generate synthetic data accordingly to the distribution I think the best to do is use some random approach instead of attempting to solve it by linear algebra.

The size of the data to be generated is `206340`, so it easily fits in memory.

A simple way to construct a data sample such that the frequency of the category `i` is `f[i]` is to set the attribute of `f[i]` elements to `i`. We can easily do this using numpy as

```
start = 0
for i, fi in enumerate(f):
  category[start:start+fi] = i
  start += fi
```

Also, the frequencies are invariant to permutations.

So what we can do is to assign people to households so that `n` people are assigned to each household of size `n`, and `ppl_by_household_size[i]` people are assigned to households of size `i+1`. Then we assign age groups accordingly to `ppl_by_age_group`, and finally we shuffle the age_group array.

This will give a random sample where
the person `i` lives is in the age group `age_group[i]` and lives in the household with index `household_id[i]`, that has size `household_size[i]`, from these arrays you can easily transform the data to the desired format.

```py
ppl_by_age_group = [45196, 148949,  12195]
ppl_by_household_size = np.array([
    2276,9366,23739,47636,42475,28338,3675,3728,3672,3830,
    3894,3792,3770,3710,3795,3648,3672,3744,3800,3780])
# check if a solution exists
assert np.all(ppl_by_household_size % np.arange(1, len(ppl_by_household_size)+1)) == 0)
assert np.sum(ppl_by_household_size) == np.sum(ppl_by_age_group)
```

```py
nppl = np.sum(ppl_by_age_group)
age_group = np.zeros(nppl, np.int8)
household_size = np.zeros(nppl, np.int8)
household_id = np.zeros(nppl, np.int32)
cppl = 0
nhouseholds = 0
for i,n in enumerate(ppl_by_household_size):
    # this will assign ppl_by_household_size[i] to 
    # ppl_by_holsehold_size[i] // (i + 1) households
    # so, each household will have (i + 1) members
    household_id[cppl:cppl+n] = nhouseholds + np.arange(n) // (i+1)
    household_size[cppl:cppl+n] = i+1
    cppl += n
    nhouseholds += n // (i+1)

cppl = 0
for i,n in enumerate(ppl_by_age_group):
    # this will assign ppl_by_household[i] members to
    # age group i
    age_group[cppl:cppl+n] = i
    cppl += n
# shuffle the age groups
age_group = np.random.permutation(age_group)
```

Here it runs in 5 milliseconds

In the real world I don't expect age group and household size to be independent, but this is another subject.